# Min Heap vs Ordinary array implementation of Priority queue

Tags: performance, heap, priority-queue, dijkstra

When is it best to implement a priority queue in Dijkstra's as a min heap and when is it better to use an ordinary array?

One has Running time `O(V^2 + E)` and the other `O((V+E)logV)`. When `E< V`, then 
`O(V^2+E) = O(V^2)` and it is worse than `O((V+E)logV)=O(2VlogV)=O(VlogV)`

When `V< E`, `O(V^2 + E)= O(E^2)` and `O((V+E)logV) = O(ElogV)` so a heap implementation seems again to be better.

They also have the same space complexity i.e `O(n)`.

I assume that there are cases when a simple array implementation of a min-priority queue in Dijkstra's is better but can't really think of a case.

Comment: I can't think of a time when it's best to implement a priority queue as "an ordinary array." Regardless of how you do it, you'll have either O(1) insertion or O(1) removal. And that makes a huge difference even when the queue size is only three items. Use a binary min heap.

Comment: What I meant with the above is that you'll have either O(1) insertion and O(n) removal, or O(1) removal and O(n) insertion. Either way, it's going to be sub-optimal.

Answer (score 0):

For Dijkstra as @JimMischel said, I can't think of any example, and I don't think it exists. However, for UCS (Uniform cost search), which is focused on finding a single shortest path to a single finishing node rather than a shortest path to every node, I can think of an example. This would be involving a problem where the transition between states is uniform.

Let's say for example we are solving the 15-puzzle (all transitions have cost 1). Moreover, in this kind of problem the range of solution costs is well known, so you could have an array of states to be explored where for each cost you store a simple vector of paths with such cost. In this case, every operation has `O(1)` and it's more efficient using an array than a binary min heap.

Comment: But then if every path has the same cost, you don't need a priority queue. Just a FIFO queue.